# Liferay Service Builder creates duplicate methods

Tags: liferay, liferay-service-builder

In my `service.xml` I defined two entities `Assignment` and `Submission`, with the latter containing `<column name="assignmentId" type="long"></column>`.

After I run Gradle's `buildService`, I get this code in `AssignmentLocalService`:

```
public Assignment addAssignment(Assignment assignment);

[...]

@Indexable(type = IndexableType.REINDEX)
    public Assignment addAssignment(Assignment assignment);
```

Eclipse marks this as an error, and Gradle's `jar` task fails with:

```
error: method addAssignment(Assignment) is already defined in interface AssignmentLocalService
```

Why is Service Builder doing this?
How to prevent it from creating duplicate methods, or how to make compilation work if Service Builder is actually doing the right thing?

Comment: Any luck with Ant build on this?

Comment: @ShivamAggarwal: I have not tried with Ant. Actually the IDE did not create any Ant script, so I'd rather continue the Gradle way if possible, but I can try to write an Ant script if that can solve the problem.

Comment: Yes definitely we should give it a try once

Comment: 1 years later, but any tips?